# Save swagger-ui output to a file

Tags: c#, swagger

I have an application that provide some REST API. This API can be changed from version to version. I want to maintain change log, but it is difficult to remember all api-changes and log them by hand. I have a swagger-ui and i can see mi API any time i need it:

[image: Swagger UI imgur]

My idea is to save (some way) this output to file every time new version is released and then analyze it using some diff utility.

So the question is: how i can save my API (which I see on the screen) to a file?

Answer (score 3):

You could save the json file (typically what is in the text box in the header) and do a diff on that.

If that url doesn't contain the json, append */swagger.json*